# Is there a way to automatically move images that don't meet certain resolution criteria to a "rejected" folder?

Tags: windows, image, sorting, adobe, photo

I receive a large number of images that are submitted by various people within our company. Rather than go through all of them manually, is there a way to have images that aren't at least 300dpi and 1800px in height/width be "rejected" into a separate folder?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".  You will have to be a lot more specific with your question.  Are you thinking of writing an app or have you already started one?  What language are you writing it in?

Comment: If you are wondering if there is something in the OS that does this already.  That would be a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: My apologies! I'm either looking for something that already exists and has these features, or looking into possibly creating a script.

Comment: Someone with more Admin power than me will migratre your question over to superuser more than likely.  Or you could ask directly on SU to get an answer more quickly.

Comment: or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/